# What is the next step when having completed first neural network?

Tags: python, neural-network, mnist

I'm a big fan of the youtube channel 3Blue1Brown and his series on Neural networks really got me excited on the subject.
I decided to create my own neural network in python from scratch engaging deeply in the mathematics. So with the help from the MNIST database on hand-written numbers I got started and succeded with the task after 2 weeks.
I have since then been further developing my code so that I can adjust the number of neurons and hidden layers neatly within the code.
I also experimented with different activation functions.
The best accuracy I've gotten is about 95% with 2 hidden layers of 16 neurons and 5 minutes of training.

Now, my question is fairly vague but I am now looking for the next challenge within the area, do you guys have any suggestions?

I now have the framework set up so I'd love some new type of problem with a bigger dataset or something or maybe should I work more on my existing problem to increase the accuracy of the ouput further?

What do you guys think?

Yours,
Emil

(Here's the code if anyone is interested)

```
import pickle
import gzip
import numpy as np
import random
import time

import pickle
import gzip
import numpy as np
import random
import time

class mnistClass:
    def __init__(self, inputAmount=784, layers=2, layerSize=16, outputSize=10, loops=1, sampleSize=100):
        with gzip.open('mnist.pkl.gz', 'rb') as f:
            train_set, valid_set, test_set = pickle.load(f, encoding='latin1')
        self.A, self.y = train_set
        self.V, self.v2 = valid_set
        self.dataSize = len(self.A)
        self.inputAmount = inputAmount
        self.layers = layers
        self.layerSize = layerSize
        self.outputSize = outputSize
        self.loops = loops
        self.sampleSize = sampleSize
        self.iterations = int(self.dataSize/self.sampleSize)
        self.clock = time.time()
        self.Weights = []
        self.Biases = []
        self.initializeArrays()
        self.initializeTraining()
        print("Accuracy: " + str(self.getAccuracy()) + "%")

    def initializeArrays(self):
        for i in range(self.layers):
            if self.layers - i > 2:     #Adding middle layers
                self.Weights.append(np.random.rand(self.layerSize, self.layerSize)-0.5) 
            if self.layers - i > 1: 
                self.Biases.append(np.random.rand(self.layerSize)-0.5)
        if self.layers > 1:
            self.Weights.insert(0, np.random.rand(self.layerSize, self.inputAmount)-0.5)
            self.Weights.insert(len(self.Weights), np.random.rand(self.outputSize, self.layerSize)-0.5)
        else:
            self.Weights.insert(len(self.Weights), np.random.rand(self.outputSize, self.inputAmount)-0.5)
        self.Biases.insert(len(self.Biases), np.random.rand(self.outputSize)-0.5)

    def sigmoid(self, x, shiftType):
        if shiftType == 0:
            result = 1/(1+np.exp(-x))
        elif shiftType == 1:
            result = 2 * (1/(1+np.exp(-x))) - 1
        return result

    def sigmoidPrime(self, x, shiftType):
        if shiftType == 0:
            result = self.sigmoid(x, 0) - self.sigmoid(x, 0)**2
        elif shiftType == 1:
            result = 2*np.exp(-x)/(1+np.exp(-x))**2
        return result

    def Rdependance(self, Z, layer1, layer2, multi=False):  #How R depends on a preceeding R
        multi = layer1-layer2 > 1
        if not multi:
            if layer1 == self.layers-1:
                shiftType = 0
            else:
                shiftType = 1           
            R1_R2_differential = np.multiply(self.Weights[layer1], self.sigmoidPrime(Z[layer1]+self.Biases[layer1], shiftType)[:, np.newaxis])
            result = R1_R2_differential
        else:
            chainRule = []
            for i in reversed(range(layer2, layer1)):
                chainRule.append(self.Rdependance(Z, i+1, i))
            result = chainRule[0]
            for i in range(len(chainRule)-1):
                result = np.dot(result, chainRule[i+1])
        return result

    def RWdependance(self, R, Z, dataCaseNo, layer):   #How R depends on connecting Weights
        if layer == self.layers-1:
            shiftType = 0
        else:
            shiftType = 1
        R_W_differential = self.Weights[layer]/self.Weights[layer]
        mergeW_Z = np.multiply(R_W_differential, self.sigmoidPrime(Z[layer]+self.Biases[layer], shiftType)[:, np.newaxis])
        if layer == 0:
            R_W_differential = np.multiply(mergeW_Z.T, self.A[dataCaseNo][:, np.newaxis]).T
        else:
            R_W_differential = np.multiply(mergeW_Z.T, R[layer-1][:, np.newaxis]).T
        return R_W_differential

    def RBdependance(self, Z, layer):   #How R depends on internal Biases
        if layer == self.layers-1:
            shiftType = 0
        else:
            shiftType = 1
        R_B_differential = np.multiply(self.Rdependance(Z, self.layers-1, layer).T, self.sigmoidPrime(Z[layer]+self.Biases[layer], shiftType)[:, np.newaxis]).T
        return R_B_differential

    def integralWeightCost(self, R, Z, dataCaseNo, quadDifferential, layer): # Cost of system for weights
        if layer == self.layers-1:
            nodes = np.identity(self.outputSize)
        else:
            nodes = self.Rdependance(Z, self.layers-1, layer)
        cost_differential = np.multiply(nodes, quadDifferential[:, np.newaxis])
        cost_differential = np.sum(cost_differential, 0)
        result = np.multiply(self.RWdependance(R, Z, dataCaseNo, layer), cost_differential[:, np.newaxis])
        return result

    def integralBiasCost(self, Z, quadDifferential, layer): # Cost of system for biases
        if layer == self.layers-1:
            nodes = np.identity(self.outputSize)
        else:
            nodes = self.RBdependance(Z, layer)
        cost_differential = np.multiply(nodes, quadDifferential[:, np.newaxis])
        result = np.sum(cost_differential, 0)
        return result



    def initializeTraining(self):
        for loop in range(self.loops):
            for iteration in range(self.iterations):
                avg_cost = 0
                avg_deltaWeights = []
                avg_deltaBiases = []
                for i in range(len(self.Weights)):  #Creating zeros of weight arrays           
                    avg_deltaWeights.append(self.Weights[i]*0)
                for i in range(len(self.Biases)):                 
                    avg_deltaBiases.append(self.Biases[i]*0)
                for dataCaseNo in range(iteration*self.sampleSize, iteration*self.sampleSize + self.sampleSize):
                    if self.layers == 1:
                        shiftType = 0
                    else:
                        shiftType = 1
                    Y1 = np.zeros(self.outputSize)
                    Y1[self.y[dataCaseNo]] = 1
                    Z = []
                    Z.append(np.dot(self.Weights[0], self.A[dataCaseNo]))
                    R = []
                    R.append(self.sigmoid(Z[0]+self.Biases[0], shiftType))
                    for i in range(1, self.layers):
                        if i == self.layers-1:
                            shiftType = 0
                        else:
                            shiftType = 1
                        Z.append(np.dot(self.Weights[i], R[i-1]))
                        R.append(self.sigmoid(Z[i]+self.Biases[i], shiftType))

                    C = np.sum((R[-1] - Y1)**2)
                    avg_cost += C
                    quadDifferential = 2 * (R[-1]-Y1)

                    for i in range(self.layers):
                        avg_deltaWeights[i] += self.integralWeightCost(R, Z, dataCaseNo, quadDifferential, i)
                        avg_deltaBiases[i] += self.integralBiasCost(Z, quadDifferential, i)

                avg_cost = avg_cost/self.sampleSize
                for i in range(self.layers):
                    self.Weights[i] = self.Weights[i] - avg_deltaWeights[i]/self.sampleSize
                    self.Biases[i] = self.Biases[i] - avg_deltaBiases[i]/self.sampleSize
                print("Average cost: " + str(round(avg_cost, 4)))
            print("\n" + "*"*25 + " " + str(loop+1) +" " + "*"*25 + "\n")
        executionEndTime = round((time.time() - self.clock), 2)
        print("Completed " + str(self.loops) + " rounds of " + str(self.sampleSize*self.iterations) + " samples (sampleSize: " + str(self.sampleSize) + "), " + " in " + str(executionEndTime) + " seconds..")
        print("Layers: " + str(self.layers))
        print("Middle layer nodes: " + str(self.layerSize))
        print("Input amount: " + str(self.inputAmount))
        amountVariables = 0
        for i in range(self.layers):
            amountVariables += self.Weights[i].size
            amountVariables += self.Biases[i].size
        print("Variables: " + str(amountVariables))
        print("Output size: " + str(self.outputSize))
        time.sleep(2)

    def getAccuracy(self):
        runs = 10000
        correct = 0
        print("Testing validation set accuracy over " + str(runs) + " samples...\n")
        for i in range(runs):
            if self.layers == 1:
                shiftType = 0
            else:
                shiftType = 1
            ran = i
            Y1 = np.zeros(self.outputSize)
            Y1[self.v2[ran]] = 1
            Z = []
            Z.append(np.dot(self.Weights[0], self.V[ran]))
            R = []
            R.append(self.sigmoid(Z[0]+self.Biases[0], shiftType))
            for i in range(1, self.layers):
                if i == self.layers-1:
                    shiftType = 0
                else:
                    shiftType = 1
                Z.append(np.dot(self.Weights[i], R[i-1]))
                R.append(self.sigmoid(Z[i]+self.Biases[i], shiftType))

            result = np.where(R[-1] == np.amax(R[-1]))
            maxNum = result[0][0]
            if int(self.v2[ran]) == int(maxNum):
                correct += 1

        accuracy = correct*100/runs
        return accuracy              


instance = mnistClass(784, 3, 16, 10, 2, 100)
#(input, layers, layer size, output, loops, sample subsize)

#input          - amount of nodes in input data
#layers         - amount of layers including last output layer but not first input layer
#layer size     - amount of nodes in hidden layers
#output         - amount of nodes in output layer
#loops          - how many times to train through the entire data set
#sample subsize - what quantity of data samples to average the gradient on
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm so glad to hear about new faces joining the field of ML (specifically DL), 
That's quite an accomplishment what you said you've achieved so first of all salute.
Now as for your question, I'd suggest you take a step back and understand the concept of data exploration, and features extraction, and why those are important and how I suggest you do it is by exploring some kaggle tutorials about machine learning, trying to do some basic classification of data sets from there like the titanic data set etc...

https://www.kaggle.com/learn/overview
go for the "into to machine learning".

Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks, I will check that out. I actually didn't know there was a difference between ML and DL before ! :)

Comment: DL is a sub theme of ML, and sure, from my experience the kaggle tutorials are great! Btw, I'd appreciate if you could raise my answer or accept it for my reputation(;